# Cookie data show with unusual characters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm developer using ASP.NET. I get authentication data in login page of user and set this data in cookie then I want show for example 'username' from cookie but characters not show properly. like ��� �����

```
<% if (!MyString.Equals(null)){ byte[] bytesMyString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MyString); Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesMyString)); } %>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are either setting the cookie improperly or reading it improperly, or both. What have you done so far to isolate the problem?

Comment: i can see data properly when i show in pages but when i refresh page this data show like above characters

Comment: I do not understand your explanation. Please post your code. I think it will be very helpful for communicating the problem. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Don't be afraid to edit your original post and put the code there. That would be much easier on the eye too.  You can edit as much as you want as people ask questions. I think we will also need to see the code that actually sets and reads the cookie.